# Applying uppercase to a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble applying upper case to a column in my DataFrame.

dataframe is `df`.

`1/2 ID` is the column head that need to apply UPPERCASE.

The problem is that the values are made up of three letters and three numbers. For example `rrr123` is one of the values.

```
df['1/2 ID'] = map(str.upper, df['1/2 ID'])
```

I got an error:

`TypeError: descriptor 'upper' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode' error.`

How can I apply upper case to the first three letters in the column of the DataFrame `df`?

Comment: str is a method of the str class and expects a str not unicode, `str.upper(u"foo")-> error`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This should work:

```
df['1/2 ID'] = map(lambda x: str(x).upper(), df['1/2 ID'])
```

and should you want all the `columns` names to be in uppercase format:

```
df.columns = map(lambda x: str(x).upper(), df.columns)
```

Answer (score 132):

If your version of pandas is a recent version then you can just use the vectorised string method [`upper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.upper.html#pandas.Series.str.upper):

```
df['1/2 ID'] = df['1/2 ID'].str.upper()
```

This method does not work inplace, so the result must be assigned back.

Comment: This emits the following warning for me these days, any resolution?
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Answer (score 9):

`str.upper()` wants a plain old Python 2 string

`unicode.upper()` will want a unicode not a string (or you get TypeError: descriptor 'upper' requires a 'unicode' object but received a 'str')

So I'd suggest making use of duck typing and call `.upper()` on each of your elements, e.g.

```
df['1/2 ID'].apply(lambda x: x.upper(), inplace=True)
```

Comment: There is no `inplace` parameter for `apply` in v0.23 of panads anymore. So it seems we need to reassign the column with this solution as well.