# pandas uppercase descriptor error

Tags: python, pandas

df

```
>>> df =pd.read_csv('blah.txt' , header=None, sep='\t')
>>> df.head()
                          0                              1
0  10:116654574:116654603:-  ATAGAGTGACCCTGTGTGTGTTCTAGGTG
1    10:19614605:19614634:-  TAAACATGAAGACTTGACTTTTTTAGGTG
2    10:19621554:19621583:-  CAGCTTCAGCACCCATTACCTTTCAGAGC
3    10:90616084:90616113:-  TGAATGGACGAGTGGATCTTCAACAGGCG
4    10:90616126:90616155:-  gtttgaaatgcaCCTGTCTTTTCTAGAAG
```

df datatypes:

```
>>> df.dtypes
0    object
1    object
dtype: object
```

How can I change everything in only column 1 to uppercase

code used :

```
>>> df.columns = map(str.upper, df.columns)
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'upper' requires a 'str' object but received a 'numpy.int64'
```

Comment: I don't see a question and the error is clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31272768/42346

Comment: @erip this is my question:  trying to change everything in column 1 to uppercase.

Comment: That's still not a question.

Comment: @erip updated question

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're trying to accomplish by converting your numbers to upper.

Comment: @erip you mean alphabets in column 1 `gtttgaaatgcaCCTGTCTTTTCTAGAAG`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
 df[1] = df[1].str.upper()
```

Comment: @erip, Maybe I'm unclear on the concept, but if it answers his question, should it not be an answer? And I'm not asking that rhetorically.

Comment: Great, glad I could help.