# Convert to upper case just a subset of the colum names of my dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe with 10 columns, and I want to convert to upper case the name of just the columns 3 to 7. How could I do that ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269216/applying-uppercase-to-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Applying uppercase to a column in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31269216/applying-uppercase-to-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: note that you can apply this answer to multiple columns by selecting them with a nested list, e.g. `df[['colname1', 'colname2', ...]]`

Comment: @NoobVB & Michael Delgado (sorry Michael, I can only mention 1 person), I've followed your links but those solutions didn't work for me (I'm using Google Colab) this is why I've submitted my own anser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to `upper()` *column names*/*headers* based on their **index** (*one or multiple*):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'test1234':[100,50,10], 'abc_!-?':[200,75,5], 'Column3':[50,300,60]})
df
```

| index | test1234 | abc_!-? | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 200 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 | 75 | 300 |
| 2 | 10 | 5 | 60 |

```
df.columns = [x.upper() if x in df.columns[0:2] else x for x in df.columns]
df
```

| index | TEST1234 | ABC_!-? | Column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 200 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 | 75 | 300 |
| 2 | 10 | 5 | 60 |

How to `upper()` *column names*/*header*s based on their **names** (*one or multiple*):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[100,50,10], 'col2':[200,75,5], 'col3':[50,300,60]})
df
```

| index | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 200 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 | 75 | 300 |
| 2 | 10 | 5 | 60 |

```
df.columns = [x.upper() if x in df[['col1','col2']].columns else x for x in df.columns]
df
```

| index | COL1 | COL2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 200 | 50 |
| 1 | 50 | 75 | 300 |
| 2 | 10 | 5 | 60 |

Answer (score 0):

Append new uppercase col list to the unchanged part and assign it to the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c'])
df.columns = list(df.columns[0:1]) + [x.upper() for x in df.columns[1:]]
```

Outputs columns as `a, B, C`